# Getting strange character returned with preg_replace originating from reference

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to use `preg_replace` to match all youtube links in a string and replace them with something else.

I will matching standard links and full links within `[youtube][/youtube]` tags.

Example of what will match:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rB2uwRIVo1I&foo=jpiadSpjpj&moo=foo&cow=123
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rB2uwRIVo1I&amp;foo=jpiadSpjpj&moo=foo&cow=123
[youtube]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rB2uwRIVo1I&foo=jpiadSpjpj&moo=foo&cow=123[/youtube]
[youtube]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rB2uwRIVo1I&amp;foo=jpiadSpjpj&moo=foo&cow=123[/youtube]
```

Example of what will NOT match:

```
[youtube]rB2uwRIVo1I[/youtube]
```

Now, all this is working fine when testing with `preg_match`; and I tried out `preg_replace` with the following code:

```
$data = file_get_contents('data-all.txt');

$data = preg_replace('#(?:(?:\[youtube\])\s*)?(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com)/watch\?[^\s]*v=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)[^\s]*(?:\s*(?:\[/youtube\]))?#im', "[youtube]\0[/youtube]", $data);

echo $data;
```

Now I am trying to replace all matches with their respective youtube ID's within `[youtube]` tags like this:

```
[youtube]rB2uwRIVo1I[/youtube]
```

This is also working fine, however the text placed inside the `[youtube]` is a strange character and not the youtube ID of the video.

Example:

[image]

I also tried with the `\1` reference and got the same result.

What am I doing wrong here? Is this some kind of charset issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either escape the backslash in your replacement string or use `$n` instead. By trying to use `\0` and `\1` you're inserting the character codes with values of 0 and 1, respectively. Also, since you want the first capture group, you want 1, not 0; 0 is the entire matched string.

IOW, change this:

```
"[youtube]\0[/youtube]"
```

To either:

```
"[youtube]\\1[/youtube]"
```

Or

```
"[youtube]$1[/youtube]"
```

The latter is generally the preferred one. [The documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) contains more information.

Answer (score 2):

Just use single quotes instead of double quotes in the replacement part.

```
$data = preg_replace('#(?:(?:\[youtube\])\s*)?(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com)/watch\?[^\s]*v=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)[^\s]*(?:\s*(?:\[/youtube\]))?#im', '[youtube]\0[/youtube]', $data);
```

Seems like you need to use `\1` in the replacement part to get your desired output.

```
$data = preg_replace('#(?:(?:\[youtube\])\s*)?(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com)/watch\?[^\s]*v=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)[^\s]*(?:\s*(?:\[/youtube\]))?#im', '[youtube]\1[/youtube]', $data);
```

Comment: Oh ok...... so you can either use `\\1` or `\1` as long as you're using single quotes on the latter?

Comment: if you use single quotes, `\1` would be enough. You don't need to use `\\1`